# How to change the locale in R on Ubuntu

Tags: r

I want to change the language in R but I don't know how to find and open the .Renviron file to edit it.
Any other way to do this in Ubuntu will also work for me.

I expect to see the R console in English, I also want to see this not for a separate session but on an ongoing basis

Comment: Have you looked at [`Sys.setlocale`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/locales.html)?

Comment: Otherwise, you can use `fn <- file.path(Sys.getenv("HOME"), ".Renviron")` for the default location of where `.Renviron` can be placed; if `file.exists(fn)` is false, then create it in whatever text editor you prefer. If you're using RStudio's IDE, then that should work fine.

Comment: @r2evans, post as answer ?

Comment: I thought about it @BenBolker, I'm not exactly sure what the OP really needs here. If it's just identification of the `Sys.setlocale` function, then does this need to be a Q&A? \*shrug*

Comment: yes, I guess `nano ~/.Renviron` or `vi ~/.Renviron` or `emacs ~/.Renviron` would also work.

Comment: Can you show the full cycle of replacing one locale with another and publish it as an answer?

Comment: All you need to do from the command line is `LANGUAGE=en.US R` and R should start in English.  In Ubuntu, you're probably not starting R from the command line, but there's probably a way to do something equivalent depending on how you do start it.  If you can't figure that out, add some more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Locale and language are not necessarily the same thing. Anyhow, we need to edit the `~/.Renviron` file, which doesn't necessarily exist yet.

To permanently change the **locale** for R (only), we may want to append `LC_ALL=C` to the `~/.Renviron` file;

```
$ echo "LC_ALL=C" >> ~/.Renviron
```

if it didn't exist yet, it gets created automatically. C denotes the C language whose default setting is English. It sets "LC_COLLATE", "LC_CTYPE", "LC_MONETARY" and "LC_TIME" at the same time, so we can kill two birds with one stone. Note, that in R there are some other categories:

```
$ Rscript -e .LC.categories
[1] "LC_ALL"         "LC_COLLATE"     "LC_CTYPE"       "LC_MONETARY"   
[5] "LC_NUMERIC"     "LC_TIME"        "LC_MESSAGES"    "LC_PAPER"      
[9] "LC_MEASUREMENT"
```

To just set the **language**, instead we can do

```
$ echo "LANGUAGE=en_US" >> ~/.Renviron
```

To see the file while editing you we can also use `nano`.

```
$ nano ~/.Renviron
```

To undo settings, simply delete the corresponding line or comment it out with a hash tag `#`.

Also see respective [R manual page on locales](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/locales.html).